# Is it true that $\operatorname{ord}(a) \mid 26 \iff a^{26} = e$ when $a$ in a group?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $\operatorname{ord}(a)k = 26$ for some $k$. Then $\operatorname{ord}(a) = \frac{26}{k}$ so that $a^{\frac{26}{k}} = e$ and $a^{26} = e$ if $k = 1.$

There's also this lemma that says if $a^m = e$ and $a$ in a group, then $\operatorname{ord}(a) \mid m$. Seems like this lemma proves the converse.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think it does.

Comment: @Joanpemo, thanks. Just checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\operatorname{ord}\,a = k$ then $a^k = e$. If $k \mid 26$, then $26 = km$ for some integer $m$. So $a^{26} = a^{km} = (a^k)^m = e^m = e$. the other direction is obvious.